# How to write if-condition in Haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

How to write `if` and `if`-`else` statements in Haml for a Ruby on Rails application?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

HAML is indentation based , and the parser can be tricky.You don't need to use "- end" in Haml. Use indentation instead.In Haml,a block begins whenever the indentation is increased after a Ruby evaluation command. It ends when the indentation decreases.Sample if else block as follows.

```
- if condition
  = something
- else
  = something_else
```

A practical example

```
- if current_user
  = link_to 'Logout', logout_path
- else
  = link_to 'Login', login_path
```

**Edit :** 
If you just want to use if condition then

```
 - if current_user
  = link_to 'Logout', logout_path
```

Comment: But how to use only if modifier

Comment: just use if like i have edited in the answer.no need to have end.The indentation will do the rest.

Comment: An answer to your practical question: link_to_if
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_if

Comment: I wanted to have another non output statement inside the if like 

    - if current_user
    -     i = 5

and was wondering why it wasn't working though I've indented it! Finally realised the - has to be indented :)

Comment: How to add `or` operator to the condition?

Comment: Only thing confusing me about this answer, is how to have multiple lines in the condition statement with just a single '='. There doesn't seem any point to using the = if indenting will do it

Answer (score 21):

In haml two operators are used for ruby code.

- `=` is used for ruby code which is evaluated and gets inserted into document.

Example:

```
= form_for @user
```

- `-` is used for ruby code which is evaluated and NOT get inserted into document.

Example:

```
- if @user.signed_in?  
  = "Hi"  
- else  
  = "Please sign in!"
```

Comment: Please note you do not really need `=` if you want to output plain string like `Hi` or `Please sign in`. `=` is only necessary for evaluating Ruby, like `= "Hi, #{@user.name}"`

Answer (score 9):

In haml, use the `-` (dash) to indicate a line is Ruby code. Furthermore, indention level indicates block level. Combine the two for if/else statements.

```
- if signed_in?
  %li= link_to "Sign out", sign_out_path
- else
  %li= link_to "Sign in", sign_in_path
```

is the same as the following code in ERB:

```
<% if signed_in? %>
  <li><%= link_to "Sign out", sign_out_path %></li>
<% else %>
  <li><%= link_to "Sign in", sign_in_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put condition inside your tag

```
%section{:class => "#{'new-class' if controller.action_name == 'index'}"}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is another variation

```
%nav(class="navbar"){class: content_for?(:navbar_class) ? yield(:navbar_class) : nil}
```